# Submit a Freeform and a Safecracker form together with one button

Tags: expressionengine

I'm using Javascript to trigger two separate forms with a single submit button.

One form is a Freeform form and the other is a Safecracker form.

It works OK, but is there a better way?

Comment: That is probably the easiest/best way.  The other way that I could think of is not a better alternative.

Comment: @Samsull I see you've asked and answered a few EE questions on here - would be great if you could support our proposal for a dedicated site http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46387/expressionengine?referrer=AwnV9oYF5EKlETXKp3ZQQw2

Answer (score 3):

There is no way in HTML to submit two forms at once, without using javascript. So yes, this is probably the best way to go about it.

Your only other option would be to write an EE PHP module which accepts your form input, then sends it to both Freeform and Safecracker. That would probably be far more trouble than it's worth though.

Comment: I've gone the JavaScript route before, and it works just fine, even though I wish there should be a better route.